# What is the C# equivalent of Get-AzureRmResource in .NET SDK for Azure?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, powershell

I would like to know if there are any .NET method to get all resources under a subscription. This is available in PowerShell in the cmdlet: Get-AzureRmResource.

Thanks

Comment: Googling for `C# Azure Resource Manager` returns links to the Azure SDK docs in the top results: [Azure Resource Manager libraries for .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/resource-manager?view=azure-dotnet). The docs point to Github sample projects [like this one](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/resources-dotnet-manage-resource) for managing resources with the resource manager. Have you tried something but failed?

Comment: Yes, I looked for them in the docs as well as the class library but never found any. I would like to really make sure that I didn't miss anything by posting this question; cause my development will depend on this.

Comment: `I would like to know if there are any .NET method to get all resources under a subscription`

I am unable to find the .NET equivalent of the powerShell cmdlet `Get-AzureRmResource` which will list all resources under a subscription

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.resourcemanager.resourcesoperationsextensions.list?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: Thanks, @Akiyoshi Tsuchida
You have saved a lot of development time!

Comment: Apparently, I was searching for this in the IAzure interface instead of the IResourceManager
`facepalm`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the British would say, Good Grief!

**TL;DR**

Try :

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent;
...

var rm = ResourceManager.                    
                .Configure()
                .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
                .Authenticate(credentials)
                .WithDefaultSubscription();

var resources= rm.GenericResources.List();

foreach(IGenericResource res in resources)
{
    ....
}
```

**TL;DR 2**

Some comments point to the [ResourceOperationsExtensions.List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.resourcemanager.resourcesoperationsextensions.list?view=azure-dotnet) extension method. That requires an `IResourceOpearations` instance though. This is available through the [IResourceManagementClient.Resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.resourcemanager.fluent.iresourcemanagementclient.resources?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Management_ResourceManager_Fluent_IResourceManagementClient_Resources). This is accessible through the [ResourceManager.Inner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.resourcemanager.fluent.resourcemanager?view=azure-dotnet) property:

```
var rmOps=rm.Inner.Resources;
var resources = rmOps.List(someODataQuery);
```

**Long version**

Azure's management works by exposing REST interfaces. In the end, both the Azure SDK and the Powershell commandlets will call that REST interface. You could use `Fiddler` or another debugging proxy to capture and reuse the

The Powershell commandlets are implemented on top of the SDK which means you can [look at the source code itself](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/blob/1bcbe7b1f7a3323ac98f7754ba03eeb6b45e79f2/src/Resources/ResourceManager/Implementation/Resource/GetAzureResourceCmdlet.cs#L174).

The commandlet uses the [ResourceManagerSdkClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.commands.resourcemanager.cmdlets.sdkclient.resourcemanagersdkclient?view=azurerm-ps) class's [ListResources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.commands.resourcemanager.cmdlets.sdkclient.resourcemanagersdkclient.listresources?view=azurerm-ps) method with an OData query generated from its parameters:

```
result = this.ResourceManagerSdkClient.ListResources(odataQuery);
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't help since the commandlets use their own low-level abstrations, while the [Azure RM libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/resource-manager?view=azure-dotnet) use different abstractions and interfaces. `ListResources` tells us that we need to query a GenericResource though.

The [Azure Resource Manager libraries repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net) is hosted on Github. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/resource-manager?view=azure-dotnet) doesn't show how to get to [ResourceManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.resourcemanager.fluent.resourcemanager?view=azure-dotnet) though. Searching in the repo itself, shows how to `ResourceManager` is used in [the tests](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net/blob/0ea10a867c2e759bb05a929726cd7b18c20b0a6b/Tests/Fluent.Tests/Common/TestHelper.cs#L151).

[ResourceManager.GenericResources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.resourcemanager.fluent.resourcemanager.genericresources?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Management_ResourceManager_Fluent_ResourceManager_GenericResources) provides access to the same generic resources that the Powershell command uses. That property's type is [IGenericResources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.resourcemanager.fluent.igenericresources?view=azure-dotnet) which in turn implements [ISupportsListing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.resourcemanager.fluent.core.collectionactions.isupportslisting-1?view=azure-dotnet) which gives us access to [List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.resourcemanager.fluent.core.collectionactions.isupportslisting-1.list?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Management_ResourceManager_Fluent_Core_CollectionActions_ISupportsListing_1_List)

The docs don't make it clear whether those interfaces are explicitly implemented. The code may need explicit casting.

`IGenericResources` implements `ISupportsListingByResourceGroup` and `ISupportsListingInResourceGroupByTag` too, which can be used to search by resource groups and tags.

Googling for `ResourceManager.GenericResources` or `GenericResources.List()` etc doesn't produce relevant results. The terms are too ... generic.

I think I'll take a break now.

Comment: From your first answer: there doesn't appear to be a `WithDefaultSubscription` method, only a `WithSubscription` method. What did you reference to get that? (is it an extension method somewhere?)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `Azure Resource Manager libraries for .NET`, details in this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/resource-manager?view=azure-dotnet).

And in the [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/resources-dotnet-manage-resource), there is a sample project your can download and use it for testing. In this sample project, you can create/update/**list resources(which is equivalent to the get-AzureRmResource**)